# Should I avoid making private field variable public for convenience?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have two objects, A and B. Right now, B stores A as a local class variable.

```
class B
{
    A myA;
}
```

Now, B has a bunch of methods which uses its inner `myA` to do some stuff, and I can use those methods since they are public.

But sometimes, I need to use the `myA` itself. So what I did was to make it public, and then I could write `myB.myA.someMethodFromA()`.

Is this okay, or is it bad style? I mean, I know that I could just provide indirect accessors to `myA` via methods in the B class, but that seems unnecessary when I can just directly access `myA`.

For example, if `myA` has a method `doStuffviaA`, I'd rather say `myB.myA.doStuffViaA()`, than first having to write a method in B that says

`void doStuffViaB() { myA.doStuffViaB() }`

But, of course making `myA` public means that it can be changed without `B` knowing about it. WHAT TO DO?

Comment: "_making `myA` public means that it can be changed without `B` knowing about it._" So, the core question is that, does `B` needs to know about such changes. If yes: the solution seems obvious. If no: it's a matter of taste, and preference.

Comment: You may want to actually provide a better interface rather than expose an implementation detail.

Comment: If `B` needs control over the value of `myA` then a public variable is wrong, wrong, wrong.

Comment: In general, I advise against doing that.  There may be specific cases where it makes sense.  But by and large, for OOP in my experience, it's best to abide by [TDA](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) as much as possible.

Comment: I think this is the time to think about if you really need myA to be a member of B. Alternatives could be that myA is standalone object and B only has a reference to it. This of course is ok only if myA can have modifications done to it that B doesn't need to know about. Here declaring functions const might help with readability.  Maybe you need to split A into two classes, one inside B and one outside, which has a reference to the B class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, making it `public` circumvents encapsulation and code can creep in that puts your object into an ill-defined state.

A half-way house option would be to supply

```
const A& getMyA() const
{
    return myA;
}
```

since then, at least, only `const` functions can be performed on the `myA` member if accessed using this function. I'm hoping, of course, that `doStuffViaA` *is* `const`, then you'd write

```
myB.getMyA().someMethodFromA();
```

Answer (score 2):

> WHAT TO DO?

It depends and is in fact quite dependent on the specific scenario. Generally, I'd advice you to

- use public data members within plain, invariant-free `struct`s only ([C2](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c2-use-class-if-the-class-has-an-invariant-use-struct-if-the-data-members-can-vary-independently))
- use a `class` once you have some invariant, make data members `private` ([C2](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c2-use-class-if-the-class-has-an-invariant-use-struct-if-the-data-members-can-vary-independently), [C8](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c8-use-class-rather-than-struct-if-any-member-is-non-public))
- avoid getters if possible.

If the latter is not possible (e.g. due to "design constraints" or a burning desire for "convenience"), you can provide a getter as posted in [@Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53063791/9593596). Alternatively, you can pass a pointer to an `A` member function or a function accepting an `A&` parameter to a member function template of `B` with associated function parameter, e.g.

```
#include <functional>

class B {
   public:
      template <class MemberFct, class ...Args>
      decltype(auto) invokeOnA(MemberFct fct, Args&&... args)
      {
         return std::invoke(fct, a, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }

   private:
      A a;
};
```

Note that this requires C++17. Given a member function `A::doStuff(int)`, this template can be instantiated and invoked with

```
B b;

b.invokeOnA(&A::doStuff, 42);
b.invokeOnA([](A& a){ a.doStuff(42); });
```

which solves the problem by another level of indirection and without a getter method. Note, however, that the approach is qualitatively very similar to providing a getter method, i.e., having a fancy function template doesn't free you from a justification why it's necessary to break encapsulation in the specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already hit the crucial point:

> But, of course making myA public means that it can be changed without
>   B knowing about it. WHAT TO DO?

Making a member public or private is not just about convenience. Ask yourself: Are there invariants that my class relies on that can break if the member is public?

Only if you can definitely answer this with "no" you can make a member public. However, in that case you could ask: Why is it a member of the class anyhow?

Consider this simple broken example:

```
struct foo { 
    int a,b,sum;
    foo(int a,int b) : a(a), b(b), sum(a+b) {}
};
```

To ensure that `sum == a+b` always holds, none of the members should be public. On the other hand, consider `std::pair`, which is just a data structure, so having `first` and `second` public is fine.